# I'm trying to run mopidy music server but the port 6600/6680 which it uses is already in use by python

Tags: 14.04

I'm trying to run mopidy music server but the port 6600/6680 which it uses is already in use by python so I closed python by using the command `pkill python`
however that didn't close the post as it's still in use by python :(
Is there a way to close the port without having to remove python?

Regards

Comment: Mopidy is a Python application, so it is of little surprise that your ports were assigned to a Python application. Your issue may be a different one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you install "mopidy"? Did you follow the instructions on their site?

If yes (you installed mopidy with apt-get install ...): mopidy has been installed as a service and therefore is started whenever you start your system. So, the process monitoring your ports 6600/6680 is actually mopidy. Just configure your local music source (some local directory in which you have some music) and then make mopidy rescan your local source. You should be up-n-running after that.

If not (you installed mopidy not with apt-get, but in some other way): specify details of installation so we may have a clue about what's going on.

Reading the fine manual (RTFM) may help. :)

HTH!